searching the type of custom fields for shopware 6 app
I'm writing an app for shopware 6.6 and want to add some custom fields.
Managed to add them to the  <related-entities><product_manufacturer/>
but can't find the type of an html field.
What are the type of fields and how can i selcet the type?
Missing detailed informations at the dos page.
Thanks
<editor name="text_2"\>
\</editor\>

or
<html name="text"\>
<position\>1\</position\>
<label lang="en-GB"\>Description\</label\>
<label lang="de-DE"\>Beschreibung\</label\>
</html>

not working - only
<text name="kk">


Found the solution:
link the IDE to the https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/shopware/trunk/src/Core/Framework/App/Manifest/Schema/manifest-2.0.xsd
